# Select all rows if @Parameter = NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I have a stored procedure with a parameter, `@PolicySymbol`, which can accept multiple values. For that I am using a split string function: `StringOfStringsToTable`

If user selects `@ControlNo`, then I want to bring data for that `controlNo` no matter what value is set for `@PolicySymbol`.

If `@PolicySymbol` = NULL I want to bring all data for `controlNo` no matter what policy symbol it related to.

Here is the code sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ControlNo int, policy_symbol varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #Test 
VALUES (1111, 'CSE'), (2222, 'PRE'), (3333, 'CSE'), (4444, 'GLG'),
       (4444, 'PRE'), (4444, 'GLS') 

DECLARE 
    @ControlNo int = 1111,
    @PolicySymbol varchar(50) = NULL 

SELECT DISTINCT ControlNo, policy_symbol
FROM #Test
WHERE ControlNo = COALESCE(@ControlNo, ControlNo)
 -- here, if parameter @PolicySymbol IS NULL I want to include all policy symbols
  AND policy_symbol IN (SELECT String FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable] (@PolicySymbol, ','))

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: Also you should replace `[dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable]` with [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) unless you have to keep ancient compatibility level for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple, logical `OR` does the trick.

```
WHERE ControlNo = COALESCE(@ControlNo, ControlNo)
-- If parameter @PolicySymbol IS NULL I want to include all policy symbols
AND (
    @PolicySymbol IS NULL
    OR policy_symbol IN (SELECT String FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable] (@PolicySymbol,','))
)
```

Comment: Exactly the way I approach it Dale K